# Can I use 'epistemological' in my action research paper?

Tags: research

I am studying for an MA as an artist-teacher. I am currently writing an Action Research essay following a recent exhibition of my work. Having explained why action research is an appropriate approach, reflective, qualitative analysis etc, I want to round up this section by saying the craft I have used is mirrored in my approach to writing. So, does the following make sense.....?

> "The architecture of my practice, the research and the production of
>   artefacts, mirror each other; knitting has many subtexts and the
>   breaking and joining of crockery can be seen as a metaphor for my
>   epistemological discoveries in investigation."

Comment: Actually, I think I'll use 'empirical' instead, just to be on the safe side!

Comment: "Discoveries in investigation" seems a bit redundant and clunky, in my opinion. You might consider rephrasing.

Comment: You **can** use any word you like; but as the immortal Inigo Montoya said, I don't think that word means what you think it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the sentence would be stronger without it. 'Epistemological' has a lot of philosophical connotations that seem ill-fitting in the context of the sentence (and almost redundant as well).

*Aside*: I would also note that the first part of the sentence also seems to bear a bit of ambiguity in verb-subject agreement. For example, you include two nouns (marked as being unnecessary by the use of the comma) in explication of the main subject 'architecture of my practice'. These two unnecessary descriptions of your main subject dictate the form of your verbal phrase 'mirror each other'. But this seems to leave your main subject hanging in the wind, without any verbal phrase of its own. This can easily be fixed by making the two nouns used as additional descriptors the main subjects of your sentence.